# Traditional dance lessons for tourists in Korea

Tags: south-korea, study, culture, activities

The [Learn](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/South_Korea#Learn) section of Wikivoyage's guide to South Korea mentions dancing as something you can learn, and mentions as an added bonus that you wear *Han Bok*, traditional Korean clothing.

I tried looking for information, but I mainly came across pages talking about non-traditional dancing (eg K-pop), lessons for long-term residents, or lessons outside of Korea. (My google skills may be lacking - are there any specific terms to specifically focus on traditional Korean dancing?)

Where can I learn traditional dance in South Korea, preferably at a place aimed at tourists?

Comment: "lessons for long-term residents" - do they ask for your residency visa before signing up?

Comment: @JonathanReez as in multi-week courses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CoréART offering might suit:

> Korean Traditional Musical Instruments & Dance Class
>
> **Overview**
>   Are you interested in Korean traditional music and dance performance? This is your chance to experience and learn some of the Korean traditional musical instruments and theatrical performances at the Korean culture and art center - CoréART. You will enjoy this fun experience while you perform with the class at the end of the lesson!
>
> **Option 1) Sangmo & Beona Twirling Class**
>   Try twirling a Sangmo (hat with a long ribbon on top) and Beona (a spinning plate) in a matching costume as you might have seen in some performances.
>
> **Option 2) Samulnori Class**
>   If you are a musical person, you can learn how to play one of the four Korean traditional musical instruments, Janggu (an hourglass-shaped drum) and Buk (a barrel drum similar to the bass drum) used in Samulnori. Samulnori is an interactive open stage musical performance, which basically means 'four instruments' and refers to the four instruments (kkwaengwari, jing, janggu, and buk) played by the musicians.
>
> **Option 3) Talchum Class**
>   Alternatively, you can make your own mask and learn the art of Talchum (Korean traditional mask dance).

[CoréART](http://www.coreart.pro)
432-1909 Shindang-dong, Jung-gu,
 
Seoul, Korea
82. 2. 2666. 3746
haera5959@naver.com

The classes, held at the CoréART center, are booked via the [Trazy web site.](https://www.trazy.com/experience/detail/korean-traditional-music-dance-class#tab:destination) Each class is priced at $30 USD, and lasts for 1 hour 30 minutes. Classes have to be booked 3 days in advance, are available weekdays, and need a minimum of 2 persons to be held.

Comment: For other people reading this: the English-language information is from Trazy, with the only English-language information from CoreArt being the [contact info](http://coreart.pro/?page_id=7458)